# java double split to String[ ][ ]

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm having a problem coming up with a way to take a string and use `.split()` twice to make a nested array.

For example if I have the string `1|2|3#1|2` and then I use `split("#")`, I end up with: `[ "1|2|3" , "1|2" ]`.

I then want to `.split("|")` the inside strings somehow, so I end up with: `[ [1,2,3] , [1,2] ]`.

But it needs to be a `String[][]`.

I already tried using an ArrayList as the as the external one so I had an ArrayList and then just used `.add()` to build it up with each of the internal arrays.

But then I could not figure out how to convert it to a `String[][]`.

I'm probably missing something obvious but I've been trying for around an hour and have had no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. Once you've got the `String[]` after the first `split`, allocate your `String[][]` and then fill it in in a loop, splitting the strings in the first array:

```
String str = "1|2|3#1|2";
String[] strs = str.split("#");
String[][] result = new String[strs.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = strs[i].split("\\|");
}
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/oA4Ek2)

Note that since `split` accepts a string defining a regular expression, you have to escape the `|` in it (because `|` has special meaning in regular expressions). You escape things in regular expressions with a backslash. Since I'm using a string literal to write the regular expression, to put a backslash actually in the string, I have to escape it (with another backslash).

Or with streams (with thanks to [ChenZhou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9087401/chenzhou) for pointing 80% of the way there), got the rest of the way thanks to [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)):

```
String[] strs = "1|2|3#1|2".split("#");
String[][] result = Stream.of(strs).map(e -> e.split("\\|")).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/lkosE1)

Comment: why is there a \\ in the "\\|"

Comment: @Aspwilenson - Hit refresh, I forgot to explain it initially but I realized almost immediately and edited in the explanation.

Comment: that was the the first thing i tried, but i did not know about the \\ and gave up on it. thank you

Comment: @Aspwilenson - It's a common "gotcha" everyone has to learn at first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] array = "1|2|3#1|2".split("#");
String[][] objects = Stream.of(array).map(e -> e.split("\\|"))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(objects));
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: That produces an `Object[]`, not a `String[][]`.

Comment: `.toArray(String[][]::new)` gets the rest of the way there.